# how to start worker in djcelery

Tags: django, django-admin, djcelery

how can I start a worker in djcelery using django.I am new to django and djcelery.I installed django and djcelery.but I don't know how to start the worker and how to add the worker and task.sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

You generally start a celery worker using the following command:

```
$ celery -A project worker -l info
```

Where -A is your application / project.

Since you are using djcelery, you can run it using manage.py too:

```
$ python manage.py celery worker
```

Read [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process)